# Nuodb Memory and CPU usage reached high

Tags: cpu-usage, nuodb

[image]While accessing NuoDB database from Java application, In Task manager tool getting CPU and Memory usage reached 99% almost and I tired with NUODB 2.4 ,2.5 and 2.6 versions but finally i am getting same issue.

Present my windows server hardware configurations are below.

RAM : 12 GB (3 processors ) and 
Hard disk : 100 GB

Please give any suggest to come this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see from the task manager MANY "NuoDB Server" processes running
(the picture shows 7 NuoDB processes running on that server),
It might be having too many TEs or too much memory configured for NuoDB on 
that single server as a potential for the problem or setting NuoDB incorrectly.
The following link can help you understand how to check your system settings.
http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Default.htm#Mgr-Show-Domain.htm?Highlight=--memory

Comment: Actually i found the issue, Executing one big query and it returns 1laksh records so while executing that query multiple times from clients then the PC it's self hanging and finally we splitted that query very nice manager using inner Join and avoid Left outer joins. Thanks for your reply.